# How implementing a directive to validate another field (custom form in angularjs)

Tags: forms, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive, custom-validators

I have a validation custom form, I use **validate-message-character="{{compose.limitCharacter - compose.message.length}}"** in a select and textarea like this

```
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="composeForm" >

            <select ng-change="limitComposeCharacter()" ng-selected="compose.profile" 
             ng-model="compose.profile" ng-options="userId in profiles" name="profile" 
             validate-message-character="{{compose.limitCharacter - compose.message.length}}" required>
            </select>

               number Character: {{compose.limitCharacter - compose.message.length}}

            <textarea class="form-control" ng-model="compose.message" name="message" 
    validate-message-character="{{compose.limitCharacter - compose.message.length}}" 
required></textarea>
              Form validity: {{composeForm.$valid}}
```

I have something like this:

- 1° Select User has compose.limitCharacter = 100
- 2° Select User has compose.limitCharacter = 200 etc etc.

This is my directive to check number Character is > 0

```
angular.module('App')
  .directive('validateMessageCharacter', function () {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs, c) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() {
            console.log(attrs.validateMessageCharacter);
            if(attrs.validateMessageCharacter < 0)
            {
                c.$setValidity('maxCharacter', false);
                c.$invalid = true;
            }else{
                c.$setValidity('maxCharacter', true);
                c.$invalid = false;
            }

        });
      }
    };
  });
```

It doesn't work proply when change select without change the textarea
some advice?

Comment: No. no fiddler any more

Comment: Then: No. no advice any more

Comment: what i have to do to get fiddler? I put console.log(attrs.validateMessageCharacter); but print only a number of character.

Comment: No, I said fiddle, as in **[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/)** (or **[plankr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)** or **[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/)** or **[CodePen](http://codepen.io/pen/)** or whatever). You create a little app (basically an HTML file and a JS file) that contain all necessary components to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, using an advice from the angular google group, I changed the scope.$watch to attr.$observe.
Second, the reason it validated only after typing text is that the text area is a required field.
Your code works here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/YvsuLoHzX9eqb7FhDgXA?p=preview

Comment: Tnx a lot. you are fantastic :D